# if else statements is it wrong or is my compiler that's wrong?

Tags: if-statement, wait

OK now here's a mystery that no one I ask can solve. I maybe a beginner but this is something I know I shouldn't get.

```
1>c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\movie\movie\p2 project.cpp(57): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\kevin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\movie\movie\p2 project.cpp(68): error C2181: illegal else without matching if
```

for this section here

```
int customer_menu(char signup(struct register_ regis))
{ 
    FILE *cni; /* cni means customer necessary info*/
    cni=fopen("login.txt","a+");
    if(cni!=NULL)
    {
        if (regis.category=="customer" )
        /*This is where the compiler say the error is at. Expecting a ';' here?:*/
        {  
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>~>~>menu~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~~ \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>>~>~>~>~>~ \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~ \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>to login~>~>~>~>~>~press 1 \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>to register~>~>~>~>press 2 \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>to buy ticket~>~>~>press 6 \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>to exit~>~>~>~>~>~>press 0 \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>>~>~>~>~>~ \n");
            printf("\t\t~>~>~>~>>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~>~ \n");
            scanf("%d",&choice);
        }
        else
        {
            int worker_menu(char signup(struct regis));
        }
        fclose(cni);
        /* And illegal use of else without matching if here?*/
    }
    else
    {
         printf("an error occured. please try again\n");
         system("pause");
         system("cls"); 
         char log,reg; desion(reg, log);
     }
 }
```

Do I have errors before the error comment that the compiler skip so result in such a shocking and puzzling mystery?

Comment: You probably have forgotten a closing brace or parenthesis *before* the function; then the function becomes part of that block, until the compiler comes across something that can't be part of a block anymore. Do you use an editor with matching braces/parenthesis highlighting?

Comment: I just tried to reformat the code you pasted and it seems @Evert is correct, your second comment seems to be on a line which is at the end of a block

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

> int customer_menu(char signup(struct register_ regis))
>   {

This is not a valid function declaration. It's not obvious how to fix it, either. What do you want this to mean?

Comment: I see where my stucts are wrong but that's not the point. The point is that it is asking for ";" afrter ")" but before "{" in my if statement. Thats what really getting me.

Comment: @kevinhay: it could be that the compiler is just as confused as triplee is, and that when you fix this, the other error will go away.

Comment: thanks. If most of what I put here but the only thing now is redefinitions, undeclear identifier and a few other.